# Send Queue message from BlobTrigger

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

```
   public static void RecieveMessage([QueueTrigger("hello")] string message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public static void CopyBlob([BlobTrigger("input/{name}")] TextReader input,
    [Blob("output/{name}")] out string output)
    {
        output = input.ReadToEnd();           
    }
```

how do i trigger the function RevieveMessage from inside CobyBlob? (By sending a message to the Queue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by passing in a **QueueAttribute** parameter to your CopyBlob method and setting the value of the message in the method. This will result in a message being placed in the queue with the message you provide.

```
   public static void RecieveMessage([QueueTrigger("hello")] string message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public static void CopyBlob([BlobTrigger("input/{name}")] TextReader input,
    [Blob("output/{name}")] out string output, [Queue("hello")] out string message)
    {
        output = input.ReadToEnd();  
        msg = "[message from CopyBlob]";         
    }
```